# How to remove seven low bits of a grayscale image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I wrote a script to remove the seven least significant bits and only keep the MBS for each pixel of a gray-scale 8-bit image. To do this, I mask each pixel with `0b10000000`, but am not getting the expected output.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

imageSource = 'input.jpg'
original_img = cv2.imread(imageSource,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow( "original", original_img )
result = original_img & 0b10000000
cv2.imshow( "out", result )
cv2.imwrite('out.jpg',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Original image:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r597Y.png]

Output from my code:
[image]

Desired result:
[image]

Comment: Could you describe the problem?  Masking each pixel with 0b10000000 will result in having two possible pixel values, 0b10000000=128 (middle grey) or 0 (black).  The "correct result" you show appears to have two values, 255 (white) and 0 (black).

Comment: COLOR_BGR2GRAY is not a valid mode for imread.  Start by reading the image with the [correct mode]  https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80af660544735200cbe942eea09232eb822

Comment: Please add the image you're getting with your code. A question should include both current behavior and desired behavior.

Comment: Hi @klutt , here is the image i'm getting with the code: https://imgur.com/a/6LBPa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you basically want all values that are:

- greater than 127 `(128 = 0b1000000 to 255 = 0b11111111)` to be 255,
- lower or equal 127 `(0 = 0b00000000 to 127 = 0b01111111)` to be 0.

You can avoid the binary AND `&`, and simply use the `threshold` function:

```
_, result = cv2.threshold(result, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

imageSource = 'input.png'
original_img = cv2.imread(imageSource, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imshow("original", original_img)
result = original_img & 0b10000000
_, result = cv2.threshold(result, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("out", result)
cv2.imwrite('out.jpg', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What you wanted is binary image(0, 255), so use the threshold function.